# How can I prevent JTextPane from resetting font settings if the initial text ends with a linefeed?

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane, sprint

I've run into a problem with JTextPane.  The code I am working with sets a number of font attributes, such as BOLD, ITALIC, etc.  But if the initial text ends with a single linefeed, and the user clicks on the last line, or is sent to the last line, the default font settings appear for any additional text the user types.

Specifically, this text works as I would expect: jTextPane.setText(String.format("Test This"));.

This text does not:
jTextPane.setText(String.format("Test This%n%n%n"));

I think that JTextPane may consider this to be a new paragraph.
If so, I would like to either

a.)  Know how to set a universal font that applies across the entire JTextPane instance's paragraphs.

or

b.)  tell the JTextPane instance to consider all of its editable area to be one paragraph.

Here is a toy program to show you what I mean. If you run this, and start typing at the end of the text the font will be whatever the default is for your Swing implementation.
I have also tried setting the document model of the JTextPane and using a Font instance in the JTextPane constructor.  The results are the same.

Another alternative is to use a JTextArea instance instead, but this is very complex code and I hesitate to make a change that may break some other area of the application than the one I am working in.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.SimpleAttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
import java.awt.*;

public class JTextPaneExampleOne {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JTextPane Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Container cp = frame.getContentPane();
        JTextPane pane = new JTextPane();

        String welcomeString = String.format("Welcome%n%n%nStranger!%n%n%n");
        pane.setText( welcomeString );

        pane.invalidate();
        SimpleAttributeSet attributeSet = new SimpleAttributeSet();
        StyleConstants.setBold(attributeSet, true);
        StyleConstants.setItalic(attributeSet, true);
        StyleConstants.setForeground(attributeSet, Color.red);

        pane.setSelectionStart( 0 );
        pane.setSelectionEnd( pane.getText().length() );
        pane.setParagraphAttributes( attributeSet, true );

        pane.setSelectionStart( pane.getText().length() );

        pane.validate();

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(pane);
        cp.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.setSize(400, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> a.) Know how to set a universal font that applies across the entire JTextPane instance's paragraphs.

In this case, you might be able to use [JTextPane#setLogicalStyle(Style)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextPane.html#setLogicalStyle-javax.swing.text.Style-):

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class JTextPaneExampleOne2 {
  public Component makeUI() {
    JTextPane pane = new JTextPane();

    Style def = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext().getStyle(StyleContext.DEFAULT_STYLE);
    Style body = pane.getStyledDocument().addStyle("body", def);
    StyleConstants.setBold(body, true);
    StyleConstants.setItalic(body, true);
    StyleConstants.setForeground(body, Color.RED);
    pane.setLogicalStyle(body);

    String welcomeString = String.format("Welcome%n%n%nStranger!%n%n%n");
    pane.setText(welcomeString);

//     SimpleAttributeSet attributeSet = new SimpleAttributeSet();
//     StyleConstants.setBold(attributeSet, true);
//     StyleConstants.setItalic(attributeSet, true);
//     StyleConstants.setForeground(attributeSet, Color.RED);
//
//     pane.setSelectionStart(0);
//     pane.setSelectionEnd(pane.getText().length());
//     pane.setParagraphAttributes(attributeSet, true);
//     pane.setSelectionStart(pane.getText().length());

    return new JScrollPane(pane);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
      JFrame f = new JFrame("JTextPane Example");
      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      f.getContentPane().add(new JTextPaneExampleOne2().makeUI());
      f.setSize(400, 400);
      f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      f.setVisible(true);
    });
  }
}
```